Zenject: How to implement custom dependencies?
I need to go through all the injectables in all the injectables and read from FieldInfo and inject my own dependencies.
For full understanding - I am using LeoEcs Lite and want to go through all the injected objects and inject EcsPool into them. How can I do it?
I tried through InjectContext, but did not understand how to access all objects from it.

The amazon-ecs tag is totally unrelated to LeoEcs
